# Pay later online?

Tags: contribution-page, paylater

I'm using CiviCRM's "pay later" functionality on a contribution page and have received a number of contributions that now have a "pending" status. This is good. When I receive a paper check, I can just update that contribution.

However, some donors wish to fulfill their pay-later pledge *online* instead of by check. **Is there a way for the donor to pay online such that the "pending" contribution will be automatically removed or updated?**

*Note: I am using a thermometer to display the total amount raised and it includes pay-later contributions, which is important to me. I'd like to avoid having duplicate contributions in the thermometer.*

Comment: Something exists for Events I think? https://github.com/backoffice/BOT-Partial-Payment-Extension found at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/345/is-there-a-way-to-allow-partial-payments-for-events

Answer (score 4):

Similar functionality was added as a part of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19263 which should be included in version >= 4.7.12.

What it includes -

- You need to add a `Default Invoice Payment Page` on `CiviContribute Component Settings`.

[image]

- Now any pay later contribution created by a user would contain a `Pay Now` link on `User dashboard` page `/civicrm/user?reset=1`.

[image]

- Hitting this button would take you to live contribution page where one can complete the pending contribution using CC details.

More details on the jira issue link.

Comment: looks like the JIRA ticket went through with 'no documentation required' which might be why it is proving hard to google about

Comment: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=346750980 was the flowchart required for the pay now functionality

Comment: **Warnings**: This approach currently has the following downsides: (1) enabling deferred revenue has other effects which are not yet documented, like creating bookkeeping entries automatically for member and event revenue; (2) when a payment is made with this "Pay now" link the **contribution will be linked to the "default invoice" page instead of its originally linked contribution page**; (3) the contribution may move to a different contact record based on the fields filled out at payment time.

Comment: As a result of this discussion we're going to make changes: 1) remove illogical dependence on Deferred Revenue Enabled, 2) leave original contribution page id link when paid later on a different page configured through 'Default Invoice Page' setting, 3) append source info and page id from payment page to end of source info from original pcontribution page.

Comment: See similar question at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20237/how-to-pay-later-an-event-by-credit-card. This ability should be available to authenticated users.

Comment: Can't find any documentation on this stuff. What's the purpose of the "default invoice payment page" field?

Answer (score 1):

The payment page has the following URL : .../civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=12&ccid=251 (where id is the Contribution-Page-Id and ccid is the Contribution-id) (you must force the id).

Being given the contact-id and the contribution-page-id, you can deliver this URL via a small php program (eg : before_url_pay.php?c=[current-user:civicrm-contact:id]&p=15) which fetches the contribution-id (SELECT id FROM civicrm_contribution WHERE contribution_page_id='.$page.' AND contact_id='.$contact.' AND contribution_status_id!=1), then generates and opens the URL (with ccid = the selected id).

If you use webforms, you can get the contact_id, and then parameterize the Webform Setting Redirection Location as /sites/default/your_php_directory/before_url_pay.php?c=[current-user:civicrm-contact:id]&p=15 (contrib page id)

Doing that, the user won't even need to pass via the dashboard.