# How to Pay Later by Credit Card

Tags: payment, paylater

We have some events which require very early registration, that the participants would like to pay later by Credit Card (easier than cheque)

Being given the contact_id and the contribution_id, the user can open the Credit Card Payment Form (e.g. via a small php program which fetches those 2 ids and then opens the form) :

/civicrm/payment/add?reset=1&id=1275&cid=5289&action=add&component=contribution&mode=live

where : id=contribution_id  and cid=contact_id :

[image]

But then the user still has to select the payment processor (sorry for being in french : Passerelle de paiement), which may be confusing and source of errors.

Why is this necessary, since the payment is attached to a Contribution Page, which is itself attached to a Payment Processor ?

Is there a way to have the payment_processor_id parameterized in the URL (e.g. ...&ppid=xx) ? ... or smth equivalent ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is provided in the response to "[Pay Later Online?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20456/pay-later-online?rq=1)"

Comment: thank you for your input : actually, I have seen that : https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20456/pay-later-online?rq=1 ; in fine, the payment page has the following URL : .../civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&ccid=251 (where id is the Contribution Page Id and ccid is the Contribution id) (you must force the id) : I will check that and come back to confirm

Comment: Absolutely right! Thanks for pointing that out - will be handy for future reference and I will delete my answer since that does indeed appear to be the correct one.

Comment: While there is an answer on that question, the code has been updated since then but the documentation is still lacking. I've opened an issue for that here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/issues/368