# How to setup a camping event with 2 part payment option?

Tags: civievent, payment, upload

Here are the conditions I need to meet

- Registration Cap: 15 people
- Deposit Fee: £10, a non-refundable deposit of £10 per person is due at time of registration, to reserve your space.

Payment Options (Either pay in full amount or interest-free installment option)

- First installment £45 (After which we’ll book your tickets – non-refundable)
- Final installment £55 (Other charges - non-refundable)
- Or they can pay the full £100 (excluding deposit) in one go
- Participants need to upload their photo while registering

My question is - How can I set up a fixed deposit amount & 2 part pricing option with a Maximum number of participants? If I set up Max no of participants and some people pays in 2 installments then the number would be maxed out before actually 15 people would be registered. Also, How can I give the option to upload a document that can be accessed easily? Thanks

EDIT: I have seen the other question at [Is there a way to allow partial payments for events?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/345/is-there-a-way-to-allow-partial-payments-for-events)

But Last answer received on this was in 2017 and I am wondering if there’s any better solution for this Kind Of issues by now!! The answers provided was not a straightforward solution because there’s no automated system and requires a lot more administrative workaround. I need a simple solution just like a event registration or a online contribution page. Just wondering, is it possible to create an extension that can take care of that? If it’s achievable via extension, how that can be done?

Multiple part payments can be achieved by selecting “Multiple registration for same email”. But issues is, how to restrict registration to only 15 contacts rather than 15 participants?

If they paid partially, how to send them an automated email for payment reminder?

Comment: can you clarify why your question is not a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/345/is-there-a-way-to-allow-partial-payments-for-events

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Thanks for point me to this thread. Last answered received on this was in 2017 and I am wondering if there’s any better solution of this Kind Of issues by now!! The answers provided was not a straightforward solution because there’s no automated system and requires a lot more administrative workaround. I need a simple solution just like a event registration or a online contribution page. Just wondering, is it possible to create an extension that can take care of that? If it’s achievable via extension, how that can be done? Thanks

Comment: It helps folk help you if you explain you have seen other threads and why those Answers are not helpful. perhaps update your Q with the comments above so more folk will read them.

Answer (score 1):

We have a client that runs a child after school care STEM program. Monies are due at the time of registration (one month eg in May) and then monthly (starting in Sep) for additional 9mo;

We use webfom civicrm (of course! ) with iATS payments to:

1) sign up for the Event and detemine the participant fee (conditionals factors are age, number of days, time-slots). 2) collect all contact info (parents, emergency contacts, contacts allowed to pick up the child) etc 3) use the recurring series feature in the webform civicrm -> CiviCRM
-> Contributions tab -> to enable that and to expose instalments on the webform 4) so parents can choose to pay now (all up front) or select the monthly option - this automatically creates a monthly recurring contribution with first charge now. 5) an administrator changes the next scheduled date for the recurring series to Sep 01 (so second instalment will be in Sep) 6) if you have a lot of recurring series then you can use views and civicrm entity and views bulk operations to contruct a view in which you can update multiple next scheduled dates in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood this correctly. Instead adding participant count limit to price field i would use Event setting to define maximum participant count.

I would create two required price field option of type radio

1. Fix Deposit
2. Event ticket fee

Define max count to 15 in events Info and Settings.

To support partial payment on Event fee you can try the [Registration Deposit](https://github.com/lcdservices/biz.lcdservices.registrationdeposit) extension developed by LCD Services that provides ability to define deposits on each price field options. However the extensions README says that ATM it only supports for Authorize.net and PayPal Standard.

HTH

Pradeep